# Pandas: returning last element of column value

Tags: python, pandas

I created the following function to retrieve data from an internal incident management system:

```
def get_issues(session, query):
    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0

    start = 0

    all_issues = []

    while True:
        issues = sesssion.search_issues(query, start, block_size, expand='changelog')
        if len(issues) == 0 # no more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:

        changelog = issue.changelog
        for history in changelog.histories:
            for item in history.items:
                if item.field == 'status' and item.toString == 'Pending':
                    groups = issue.fields.customfield_02219


        d = {
            'key'        :  issue.key,
            'issue_type' :  issue.fields.issuetype,
            'creator'    :  issue.fields.creator,
            'business'   :  issue.fields.customfield_082011,
            'groups'     :  groups
             }

        fields = issue.fields

        issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    return issues
```

I use this function to create a dataframe `df` using:

```
df = get_issues(the_session, the_query)
```

The resulting dataset looks *similar* to the following:

```
    key       issue_type       creator        business         groups
0   MED-184   incident         Smith, J       Mercedes         [Finance, Accounting, Billing]
1   MED-186   incident         Jones, M       Mercedes         [Finance, Accounting]
2   MED-187   incident         Williams, P    Mercedes         [Accounting, Sales, Executive, Tax]
3   MED-188   incident         Smith, J       BMW              [Sales, Executive, Tax, Finance]
```

When I call `dtypes` on `df`, I get:

```
key          object
issue_type   object
creator      object
business     object
groups       object
```

I would like to get only the **last element** of the `groups` column, such that the dataframe looks like:

```
    key       issue_type       creator        business         groups
0   MED-184   incident         Smith, J       Mercedes         Billing
1   MED-186   incident         Jones, M       Mercedes         Accounting
2   MED-187   incident         Williams, P    Mercedes         Tax
3   MED-188   incident         Smith, J       BMW              Finance
```

I tried to amend the function above, as follows:

```
groups = issue.fields.customfield_02219[-1]
```

But, I get an error that it's not possible to index into that field:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I also tried to create another column using:

```
df['groups_new'] = df['groups']:[-1]
```

But, this returns the original `groups` column with all elements.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

########################################################

**UPDATE**

`print(df.info())` results in the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 14 columns)

#     Column          Non-Null Count       Dtype
---   ------          -------------        -----
0     activity        7 non-null           object
1     approvals       8 non-null           object
2     business        13 non-null          object
3     created         13 non-null          object
4     creator         13 non-null          object
5     region_a        5 non-null           object
6     issue_type      13 non-null          object
7     key             13 non-null          object
8     materiality     13 non-null          object
9     region_b        5 non-null           object
10    resolution      2 non-null           object
11    resolution_time 1 non-null           object
12    target          13 non-null          object
13    region_b        5 non-null           object
types:  object(14)
memory usage:  1.5+ KB
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
df['new_group'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['groups'][-1], axis = 1)
```

**UPDATE:** If you get an IndexError with this, it means that at least one one your lists in empty.  You can try this:

```
df['new_group'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['groups'][-1] if x['groups'] else None, axis = 1)
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[121,234,147], 'groups':[[111,222,333],[34,32],[]]})
print(f'ORIGINAL DATAFRAME:\n{df}\n')

df['new_group'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['groups'][-1] if x['groups'] else None, axis = 1)
print(f'FINAL DATAFRAME:\n{df}')

#
ORIGINAL DATAFRAME:
   key           groups
0  121  [111, 222, 333]
1  234         [34, 32]
2  147               []

FINAL DATAFRAME:
   key           groups  new_group
0  121  [111, 222, 333]      333.0
1  234         [34, 32]       32.0
2  147               []        NaN
```

Comment: This results in an `IndexError: list out of range` error.

Comment: @equanimity Then one of the lists in the groups column must be empty.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, @pakpe, there were a few lists that were empty.  Your updated solution works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: demonstration handling empty values**

To get only the last element of each value (a Python list) in the 'groups' column, you can apply the following lambda to modify the 'groups' column inplace:

```
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x: x.pop() if x else None)
```

Working demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd

# Code for mocking the dataframe
data = {
    'key': ["MED-184", "MED-186", "MED-187"],
    'issue_type': ['incident', 'incident', 'incident'],
    'creator': ['Smith, J', 'Jones, M', 'Williams, P'],
    'business': ['Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'],
    'groups': [['Finance', 'Accounting', 'Billing'], ['Finance', 'Accounting'], None]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# print old dataframe:
print(df)

# Execute the line below to transform the dataframe 
# into one with only the last values in the group column.
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x: x.pop() if x else None)

# print new transformed dataframe:
print(df)
```

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: The solution suggested by @Vanderlei Munhoz results in an error on the production data:  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'` (probably because it's a special object type)

Comment: That is correct, if any value inside the "groups" column isn't a List the AttributeError exception will be raised. What are the real types of the "groups" column in the production dataframe @equanimity?

Comment: How would I see the *actual* types in an `object` type?

Comment: What is the output of "print(df.info())"? df being the production dataframe. @equanimity

Comment: I see the output but there is no "groups" column displayed (I guess the name is different). Check if there are any NaN/Empty values in the column with the lists--if this is the case, you will need to first handle these empty values (maybe swapping them to an empty list) before calling the .pop() method as I suggested. Please let me know if this is the case so I can update my answer accordingly. @equanimity